Cookie not displaying on Server (Frontend)
I've tried everything to try to get the cookie to display on the frontend (inspect -> application -> cookies) but it just doesn't show up. Although the frontend & backend are on different servers, I don't think it affects the cookie too much & samesite="None" should allow cookies to transfer cross domains (which is the default setting)
There are no error alerts on the frontend (console.log through inspect) or on the backend server on vscode terminal.
@app.route('/auth/register', methods=['POST']) #Creates the User
async def register_user():
    data = request.json
    email = await sanitise_input(data['email'])
    password = await sanitise_input(data['password'])
    first_name = await sanitise_input(data['firstName'])
    last_name = await sanitise_input(data['lastName'])

    try:
        [session_token, csrf_token] = await user_auth_register(email, password, first_name, last_name)                       #Authentication Register - Stage 1.2 || Stage 2.1 & 2.2 Returns csrf_token & session token

        response = make_response(jsonify({"message": "User registered successfully", 
                                          "token": session_token, 
                                          "csrf_token": csrf_token}), 201)
        
        response.set_cookie("authToken", session_token, samesite="None")

        return response

        #return jsonify({"message": "User registered successfully", "token": session_token, "csrf_token": csrf_token}), 201
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Unexpected error: {str(e)}")
        return jsonify({"error": str(e)}), 406

I've tried to fiddle with the code (below) / file & it works outside of the main project file, so I have no idea why...

Using static variables
Printing out / retrieving the cookie (there were none)
Checking for CORS(app) which was present

The link to the github poject (before I started doing cookies) is here:
https://github.com/Cawwot1/secure-software-at1-Cawwot1-main.git
I attempted to add the cookie generator in /auth/register route in Server.py (backend)
